# Can't Airdrop With CSV airdrop

Tags: erc-20, polygon, airdrop

I have created this CSV file to try and airdrop my token but I keep getting the error

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')

[CSV HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ffo7yd4w7GY-TMCUGcPxpYesVVx4ZcoOyKgnoUqSZ0E/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: The blockchain doesn't understand anything about CSVs. So I guess you're using some tool to do the airdrop? Consult their documentation

Comment: Yes sir I am using CSV airdrop from gnosis-safe but I fixed it it was all because I but receive and not receiver